# Memory issue when assigning spatial reference using GDAL

Tags: c++, gdal

I'm using [OGR](http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/) from the GDAL library to manage spatial data. Right now I have my local development environment on a Mac. The code supplied works as intended on the Mac.

But when building and running on the production Ubuntu machine I get Segmentation fault (core dumped).

The code fetches spatial data from a PostgreSQL table and loops the result. In the loop I intend to assign a OGRGeometry to a pointer and then assign the correct spatial reference. But as stated earlier I get Segmentation fault (core dumped). Other parts of the application uses similar code, but none of them are in a loop. Most of times the application just assigns spatial reference to a single geometry and then moves on.

I have added a comment where I get the memory issue.

```
OGRSpatialReference epsg3006;
epsg3006.SetWellKnownGeogCS("EPSG:3006");

for (pqxx::result::const_iterator i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i) {
    const char* wkt = i["geometry"].as<std::string>().c_str();

    // cast because OGR_G_CreateFromWkt will move the pointer
    auto pszWkt = (char*) wkt;

    OGRGeometry* polygon;
    OGRErr err = OGRGeometryFactory::createFromWkt(&pszWkt, &epsg3006, &polygon);

    // This line produces the seg fault
    polygon->assignSpatialReference(&epsg3006);

    // ..omitted code
}
```

I tried moving the code:

```
OGRSpatialReference epsg3006;
epsg3006.SetWellKnownGeogCS("EPSG:3006");
```

inside the loop without any luck.

I have tried debugging with the use of Valgrind. But it seems to prematurely exit because of some other issue as seen [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2016-August/294300.html). But that's an issue for another post.

EDIT: Have now managed to get Valgrind to work. The output can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/SJMn74ms).
I guess the problem is when freeing the memory here

```
at 0x553D4E9: OGRSpatialReference::Release() (in /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20.1.3)
```

But I'm out of ideas what to do.

I'm out of ideas. What can be the issue for the segfault on the production machine?